# AngularJS ng-disabled not working inside <td> element

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have an attribute directive called rtpUniqueWeatherSetting that applies a $validator that checks for uniqueness against an array. Here's the view:

```
    <form name="newform">
        <div>
          Form is valid: {{newform.$valid}}
        </div>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="newform.$invalid"
               class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveNew()"
               value="Submit" />
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelNew()">Cancel</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input required rtp-unique-weather-setting type="number" ng-model="newSetting[fromProp]" name="newSettingFrom" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input required type="number" ng-model="newSetting[rankProp]" name="newSettingRank" />
      </td>
    </form>
```

The directive with validator

```
require('./_index')
.directive('rtpUniqueWeatherSetting', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelController) {

      // TODO: REMOVE. FOR DEBUGGING ONLY.
      scope.$watch("newSetting", function() {
        console.log(ngModelController.$validators);
        console.log(ngModelController.$invalid);
      }, true);

      var findSetting = function(fromVal) {
        return scope.denormalizedSettingsObject.settings.find(function(setting) 
{
          return setting.from === fromVal;
        });
      };

      ngModelController.$validators.uniqueSetting = function(modelValue, 
viewValue) {
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;
        var existing = findSetting(value);
        if (existing) {
          console.log('An override starting at ' + value + ' already exists.');
          return false;
        }
        console.log('Overrides are unique.');
        return true;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

I have a `$watch` observing the ngModelController.$invalid prop, and I'm passing the value to the console. Long story short, the validator is working flawlessly, and the $invalid property is being set as true whenever it needs to be, and vice versa. However, ng-disabled doesn't seem to work as I have it .

Comment: If the custom validator is causing a problem, you should show us that code.

Comment: My bad. I've added it. The console.logs appear to be returning values as expected. My only lead now is that somehow the scope is getting messed up, and the models aren't added to the public formController?

Comment: Are you using `ng-repeat`? Could this be causing duplicate `name` attributes for inputs?

Comment: There is a `ng-repeat`, but it's in the `<tr>` above the one with this form. The name attributes are also different.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. The form was placed inside of a table. I'm not sure if that's even a good design lol. The elements/models were separated into separate `<td>`. I moved the form out of the table, into its own div and removed the  table data tags and it works now. Thanks :)

Comment: The only permitted parent of a `<td>` element is a `<tr>` element. For more information, see [MDN `<td>` Element Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).

Answer (score 0):

If you think td causing issue then try like below.

Instead of **td**  use **div** and apply css **display:table-cell** for that div

and to make aligned to center use css

```
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

}
```